# asp:listbox value not available on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all I have an asp:listbox that I populate on page load from an array that I loop through and add the items. however when the form is submited the value is always null. I have added another value in the form

```
<asp:ListItem Value="blar" Text="blar"></asp:ListItem>
```

and if I select that value it is there on the postback.

below is my page load code to populate the listbox

```
 foreach (string cntry in Countries.CountriesArray())
            {
                YrCountrySelect.Items.Add(new ListItem(cntry, cntry));
                if (Page.IsPostBack && YrCountrySelect.SelectedValue == cntry) YrCountrySelect.SelectedValue = cntry;
            }
```

does anyone know why its not passing the selected value???

Comment: Why list box,can add a dropdown and fill countries using culture info..if needed i ll give you the code..

Comment: Ive just added a dropdownbox and thats exactly the same, nothing passed through

Comment: I will paste my code below..just copy and paste in pageload..thats it..It will fetch all the countries..

Answer (score 2):

bind postback only on first pageLoad

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   //bind your listbox here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SortedDictionary<string, string> objDic = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (CultureInfo ObjectCultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
            {
                RegionInfo objRegionInfo = new RegionInfo(ObjectCultureInfo.Name);
                if (!objDic.ContainsKey(objRegionInfo.EnglishName))
                {
                    objDic.Add(objRegionInfo.EnglishName, ObjectCultureInfo.Name);
                }
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> val in objDic)
            {
                country.Items.Add(new ListItem(val.Key, val.Value));//country is dropdownlist name..
            }
```

Comment: ok as stupid as this might sound ive sorted it. On change on the select box im running some jquery that puts the selected value into an asp.net text box which I can then reference.